# C# Convert DateTime to Time zone UTC+07 and Compare two Datetime

Tags: c#, winforms, timezone, compare

In application, I'm retrieve time in web service and compare time with time in file XML, I don't know the exact time zone the web service returns so I want to convert both to the same timezone before comparing

-Time in XML file : 2022-05-16T15:37:56.000+07:00

_Time returns in web-service: 2022-05-16 15:30:00

Please help me convert time returns web service to UTC +07
In code compare time:

```
            DateTime date1 = new DateTime(time_XML.Ticks);
            DateTime date2 = new DateTime(time_Webservice.Ticks);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                //relationship = "is earlier than";
                return false;
            }  
            else if (result == 0)
            {
                //relationship = "is the same time as";
                return false;
            }  
            else
            {
                //relationship = "is later than";
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say that you want to convert to a specific time zone, but that you don't know what time zone that is. How would we know, if you do not?  Or are you asking how to compare the date and time *without* regard for time zone?

Answer (score 1):

You convert a local `DateTime` to UTC with [`ToUniversalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=net-7.0):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(time_XML.Ticks).ToUniversalTime();
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(time_Webservice.Ticks).ToUniversalTime();
// now compare them
```

Your example:

```
string dtStr1 = "2022-05-16T15:37:56.000+07:00";
string dtStr2 = "2022-05-16 15:30:00";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dtStr1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(dtStr2);
Console.WriteLine("date1: " + date1 + " kind: " + date1.Kind);
Console.WriteLine("date2: " + date2 + " kind: " + date2.Kind);
DateTime dateUtc1 = date1.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime dateUtc2 = date2.ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine("dateUtc1: " + dateUtc1 + " kind: " + dateUtc1.Kind);
Console.WriteLine("dateUtc2: " + dateUtc2 + " kind: " + dateUtc2.Kind);
```

outputs for me(germany):

```
date1: 16.05.2022 10:37:56 kind: Local
date2: 16.05.2022 15:30:00 kind: Unspecified
dateUtc1: 16.05.2022 08:37:56 kind: Utc
dateUtc2: 16.05.2022 13:30:00 kind: Utc
```

Comment: If using date.ToUniveralTime, it incorrect time in my country. I hope time returns UTC+07, sorry I'm newbie

Comment: What country and why incorrect, what utc time do you expect and what is it actually? As you can see my utc time is 7h before the offset time 7h.

Comment: When try run code in debug mode, results Time_XML: 5/16/2022 8:37:56 AM, Time_Webservice: 5/16/2022 8:30:00 AM. that's not what I want, because the actual time is : 2022-05-16T15:37:56.
my problem  here is: sometimes web service return time + 2 hours. My country: Vietnam

Comment: @Kevil: i'm not sure if i undrstand the issue but then don 't use `ToUniversalTime` with the time that has no offset(from xml) but only for the webservice